# Is there any way to execute robolectric tests on android-scala project using sbt?

Tags: sbt, robolectric

Reading the [roboletric documentation](http://pivotal.github.com/robolectric/) I see it uses maven and it expects to see a java based project and not a scala one.

However I am using intellij + scala + android as described in this [blog post](http://i-apply.blogspot.gr/2012/09/android-scala-intellij-on-ubuntu-for.html).

How could you execute robolectric tests on a android-scala project like the one above?

Answer (score 1):

As of now, there seems to be two main options:

- [RoboTest](https://github.com/zbsz/robotest) - Integrates RoboElectric with ScalaTest test library
- [RoboSpecs](https://github.com/jbrechtel/robospecs) - Integrates RoboElectric with Specs2 test library

Both of them seems easy to use. And both of then do **not** support parallel execution of tests in the same JVM. RoboTest seems to be able to run tests in parallel by forking processes for each test.